# Labeling and adding an icon to D3 SVG nodes

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to add the label and icon in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/aa1024/pen/qybrjK?editors=1010) as per this example [Labeled Force Layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642)

In my `restart` method, I have added the code

```
node.append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
   .attr("x", -8).attr("y", -8).attr("width", 16).attr("height", 16)
   .on("mousedown", mousedownNode);

   node.append("text").attr("dx", 12).attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) { return d.id });
```

after my existing code :

```
node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor")
 .attr("class", "node").attr("r", 10).on("mousedown", mousedownNode);
```

I understand that I am making the node as circle first then trying to add an icon to it, which is the issue here but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot append a `<text>` element to a `<circle>` element.

The idiomatic solution here is converting `node` into a group selection, just like Mike Bostock has in the example you shared:

```
node.enter().insert("g", ".cursor")
    .attr("class", "node");
```

Then, appending the circles and the texts to `node`:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .on("mousedown", mousedownNode);

node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.id
    });
```

And, finally, changing the  `tick` function:

```
node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
});
```

Here is the updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBepoo?editors=0010

Of course, this is just a quick refactor: you have to change other parts of your code for having `node` as a group selection.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gerardo for this very helpful CodePen entry. Apparently, the CSS overrides the JS and must be modified in order for the icon to appear, for example:

From: `.node {   fill: #000; }`

To: `.node {  fill: none; stroke: <some color so the labels appear>;}`

[My update of your update on CodePen](https://codepen.io/mondoleo/pen/MWGePOd)